# tinymce - update plugin property after editor initialization

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I need to update the colors list after init (or even on init), the plugins is `textcolor`. I'm using tinyMCE 4.1.9. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe in tinymce settings

```
tinymce.init({
  textcolor_map:  ["000000", "Black"]
});
```